# How to check if a value is equal to associative array value?

Tags: php, arrays

how can I solve this:

```
$a = array(9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$b = array(
    array("item" => 10),
    array("item" => 13)
);
```

I want to check what $a values exist in $b['item'].
in_array and array_key_exists cannot help me :(

Thanks!

Comment: see my updated answer as per your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a foreach loop will do the work for you.

```
$not_in_b = array();

foreach($b as $row)
{ 
    if(!in_array($row['item'], $a) 
    {
        $not_in_b[] = $row['item'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but I need to know which $a values are not in $b :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($b as $item){
     if(!in_array($item['item'], $a){
          echo $item['item'].' is not array $a'; //or do whatever it is you want to do.
     }
}
```